AssertionError('initial value for `x` is of type fp16, but the then block redefines it as fp32')
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VYkncZMfGFkeCEgN2IzbZIKEDkyQuJAS?usp=sharing
I am trying to fine tune a llm with this google colab, yesterday it was working perfectly but today I keep getting this error:
trainer_stats = trainer.train()


==((====))==  Unsloth - 2x faster free finetuning | Num GPUs = 1
   \\   /|    Num examples = 698 | Num Epochs = 1
O^O/ \_/ \    Batch size per device = 2 | Gradient Accumulation steps = 4
\        /    Total batch size = 8 | Total steps = 60
 "-____-"     Number of trainable parameters = 29,884,416
wandb: WARNING The `run_name` is currently set to the same value as `TrainingArguments.output_dir`. If this was not intended, please specify a different run name by setting the `TrainingArguments.run_name` parameter.
wandb: Using wandb-core as the SDK backend. Please refer to https://wandb.me/wandb-core for more information.
wandb: Logging into wandb.ai. (Learn how to deploy a W&B server locally: https://wandb.me/wandb-server)
wandb: You can find your API key in your browser here: https://wandb.ai/authorize
wandb: Paste an API key from your profile and hit enter, or press ctrl+c to quit: ··········
wandb: Appending key for api.wandb.ai to your netrc file: /root/.netrc
Tracking run with wandb version 0.18.5
Run data is saved locally in /content/wandb/run-20241106_141554-5c9y0gtx
Syncing run outputs to Weights & Biases (docs)
View project at https://wandb.ai/vonow25599-adesso/huggingface
View run at https://wandb.ai/vonow25599-adesso/huggingface/runs/5c9y0gtx
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CompilationError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-3d62c575fcfd> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 trainer_stats = trainer.train()

25 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/triton/compiler/compiler.py in make_ir(self, options, codegen_fns, context)
    111 
    112     def make_ir(self, options, codegen_fns, context):
--> 113         return ast_to_ttir(self.fn, self, context=context, options=options, codegen_fns=codegen_fns)
    114 
    115     def parse_options(self):

CompilationError: at 59:8:
    # Do logit softcapping for Gemma 2: t * tanh(1/t * x)
    if DO_SOFTCAPPING:   logits = SOFTCAP * triton_tanh(logits / SOFTCAP)

    c = tl.max(logits, 0)
    logsumexp = c + tl.log(tl.sum(tl.exp(logits - c), 0))

    if label_idx != -100:
        x = tl.load(logits_ptr + label_idx)
        # Go logit scaling for Cohere: t * x
        if DO_LOGIT_SCALING: x = LOGIT_SCALE * x
        # Do logit softcapping for Gemma 2: t * tanh(1/t * x)
        if DO_SOFTCAPPING:   x = SOFTCAP * triton_tanh(x / SOFTCAP)
        ^
AssertionError('initial value for `x` is of type fp16, but the then block redefines it as fp32')

I tried updating everything, including triton but still not working..., I just run the google colab file and get the error over and over
